# How to count values once?

Tags: tableau-api

I'm using Tableau Public to analyze a dataset of job offers. One of my charts shows the count for different job titles.

Some jobs are posted in different locations, but with the same title and date.

Is there a way to count those jobs only once?

Example:

- Java Developer - Berlin - 1 - 01.01.2017
- Java Developer - Munich - 1 - 02.02.2017
- Java Developer - London - 1 - 01.01.2017
- Android Dev - Berlin - 1 - 15.01.2017
- iOS Dev - New York - 1 - 04.02.2017
- iOS Dev - London - 1 - 03.02.2017
- iOS Dev - Berlin - 1 - 03.02.2017

They should only be counted once, when day are posted on the same date, even if they are located in different countries.

So the total numbers should be as followed.

Java Developer: 2

Android Dev: 1

iOS Devs: 2

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You could use LOD here, 
`{Fixed Date: countd(Jobs)}`

This will restrict the level of aggregation of the calculation.